# When copying values to and from ArrayBuffers in javascript are they first converted into floats?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

It doesn't come as much of a surprise to me that when I read data from an ArrayBuffer to a variable using an integer view that the variable ends up being converted to a float because of javascript's numbering system. But I am wondering if this happens every time a view is used like in this case:

```
array = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4]);
array[0] = array[1];
```

Is `array[1]` converted to a float and then converted back to a single byte for `array[0]` or is there some kind of optimization here?

Comment: This would depend on the implementation, but I doubt it would be converted to a float unless an operation that required floating-point semantics was performed on the integer. Note that this representation is internal only, they are presented to JavaScript code as an ordinary number.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Ah that's what I meant, but since javascript only supports 8 byte floats does that mean javascript has to "make a Number" during [[get]]?